# AppCompatButton drawable gravity center with dashed border

Tags: android-drawable, android-appcompat, androidx

I need to place `drawableStart` to be centered with text in `Androidx AppCompatButton` like this image?

[image]

i got the dash line background done like that

ic_dash_bg.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#d1daec" />
    <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="#667CA8"
        android:dashWidth="24px"
        android:dashGap="12px" />
    <corners android:radius="8dp" />
</shape>
```

and here's my button code

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
    android:id="@+id/issueImgBtn"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_dash_bg"
    android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_camera"
    android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Issue Photo"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:textColor="#667CA8"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/issueImagesList" />
```

and here's the result i get
[image]

**UPDATE**

I managed to make it with using MaterialCarView and AppCompatTextView

here's my solution

```
  <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        android:id="@+id/issueImgBtn"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
        app:cardElevation="4dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/issueImagesList">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="12dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_dash_bg">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Issue Photo"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="#667CA8"
                android:drawablePadding="8dp"
                app:drawableStartCompat="@drawable/ic_camera"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
```